# Eclipse project for running a BAT file?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Is there some way of creating a project in Eclipse, without any source files, that when built runs a single BAT file (either directly or via a Makefile, either would be all right)?

The goal is to split an existing project with a post-build step (a BAT-file that performs deployment) into two projects, one for building and one for running the deployment BAT-file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at creating an External Tool Launch Configuration via `Run->External Tools`  One type is `Program`, you can use that to run bat files.

Answer (score -1):

I know that this is an old question maybe the answer was irrelevant back then.
Currently in Eclipse if you right click to your projects and go to:

> Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings

The second tab is Build Steps. You can add both pre and post build steps.

I have found that sometimes the eclipse internal shell is a bit awful. So if you want to run it in Windows shell you can prepend cmd /c and add caret (^) as an escape character e.g. for a_file_with_(escaped)_chars.bat

> cmd /c "a_file_with_^(escaped^)_chars.bat"

Comment: Downvoted since this answer actually suggest a solution that is the exact reason for the question.

Comment: Yep sorry I read it in a hurry didn't notice the details. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: "The goal is to split an existing project with a post-build step (a BAT-file that performs deployment) into two projects, one for building and one for running the deployment BAT-file."